# Why only such range of constants is defined for *const_n JVM instructions?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, jvm-bytecode

According to JVM [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html), there are several instructions that are optimized for working with a specific set of constants.
Can anyone explain why only this range of constants is defined?

- iconst_n: push integer constant n, **0 ≤ n ≤ 5**
- lconst_n: push long constant n, **0 ≤ n ≤ 1**
- fconst_n: push float constant n, **0 ≤ n ≤ 2**
- dconst_n: push double constant n, **0 ≤ n ≤ 1**

I assume that this is due to the frequency of use of these constants, but
I can't find confirmation of my thoughts or any other information about it.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone explain why only this range of constants is defined?

This seemed like a good idea at the time.  The bytecode is based on older virtual machine implementations, and may have inherited these constraints.

> I assume that this is due to the frequency of use of these constants,

I did some research based on how often different instructions are used a few years after it came out and found little evidence of an empirical approach to deciding which instructions were to be 1 byte vs 2 bytes.  Then again, at the time the original design was written, very little bytecode had been generated.

Answer (score 2):

The intent has been mentioned explicitly, e.g. in [JVMS, §3.2. Use of Constants, Local Variables, and Control Constructs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.2-230):

> The Java Virtual Machine frequently takes advantage of the likelihood of certain operands (`int` constants *-1*, *0*, *1*, *2*, *3*, *4* and *5* in the case of the *iconst_<i>* instructions) by making those operands implicit in the opcode. Because the *iconst_0* instruction knows it is going to push an `int` `0`, *iconst_0* does not need to store an operand to tell it what value to push, nor does it need to fetch or decode an operand. Compiling the push of *0* as *bipush 0* would have been correct, but would have made the compiled code for `spin`¹ one byte longer. A simple virtual machine would have also spent additional time fetching and decoding the explicit operand each time around the loop. Use of implicit operands makes compiled code more compact and efficient.

¹ that’s the example code under discussion, i.e. a for loop from zero to one hundred

It’s not the only optimization of that kind, e.g. there are special instructions for accessing the first for local variables in a stack frame.

> These operations also have special support in the instruction set. In `spin`, values are transferred to and from local variables using the *istore_1* and *iload_1* instructions, each of which implicitly operates on local variable *1*.

Note also the existence of the convenient instruction *iinc*, the only one to directly operate on a local variable. So counting loops, often starting at zero or one and incrementing the counter by a small value like one, are a primary use case of these optimized instructions.

The optimizations for small variable indices is justified, as these indices are assigned in ascending order, `this` (if not `static`), followed by the parameters, followed by the first local variables. In principle, a compiler could optimize this further by reordering the variables to have the most often used variables at the optimized indices, but in practice, this doesn’t happen.

For an optimizing JVM like HotSpot, there’s surely no performance advantage when using these instructions, but they still make the bytecode a bit shorter.